# App Store's infamous Missing Push Notification Entitlement ITMS-90078 warning

Tags: xamarin, apple-push-notifications, app-store, visual-studio-2022

I have searched (and found) a number of ways this warning (see at bottom) could be resolved, but none of them work for me.

Here are my details:

1. I am using Visual Studio 2022 and Xamarin.
2. My AppId in App Store DOESN'T have Push Notifications enabled.
3. My Entitlements.plist file looks like this (for this question, I have replaced the domain and app names with xxxx and  yyyy respectively) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.xxxx.yyyy</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

4. Some commentators recommend replacing one Entitlements.plist file with 2: Entitlements.developer.plist and Entitlements.production.plist, each to be used as needed. I have tried that (copying the above Entitlements.plist content), but to no avail.

Any ideas as to how to resolve the warning, given the above info?
Thanks!

```
ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment' entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the 'aps-environment' entitlement.
```

Comment: Its likely that some nuget or library you are including has code related to notifications. Even if you aren't calling that code, there might be "initialization" code running for the nuget/library, that checks for notification privilege. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/64417 mentions *"UIApplicationDelegate method application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:*" As that forum post says, the ONLY way to eliminate the warning is to REMOVE the offending code. Unfortunately, this means "somehow" determining WHICH included nuget/library is the offending one.

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting theory.  If true, does it mean I'd have to enable Push Notifications for my app?

Comment: That would be one way to solve it. (Ideally you'd instead "somehow" find which nuget/library is making the call, then contact vendor to see if there is a fix. Not sure how to find the offendor. I guess read about each nuget, see which ones have any support for notifications.)